# How to use a regex in C# to match multiple patterns with whitespace or characters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to break up the following patterns into groups using regex

```
Law & Order Special Victims Unit S05E21 Criminal
Law & Order Special Victims Unit.S05E21.Criminal
Law.&.Order.Special.Victims.Unit.S05E21.Criminal
Law & Order Special Victims Unit - S05E21 - Criminal
```

I want to break them up into the following members

```
Showname
Season
Episode
Title
```

I'm using the following regex to break it up into groups.

```
(.*)(\s+)?(.)(\s+)?(S)(\d+)(E)(\d+)(\s+)?(.)(\s+)?(.*)/gi
```

It works for all except for the last one where it adds the - into the showname, so instead of

> Law & Order Special Victims Unit

for showname (group 1) I'm getting

> Law & Order Special Victims Unit -

How do I tell the regex that if there is a space followed by a character (the space may be optional) to pick out the character into a separate group?

To clarify the . and - in the name (separators) may or may not exist or may be something else like + or _ or something else unknown today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with something like this

```
(.*?)\s*[\.-]?\s*S(\d+)E(\d+)\s*[\.-]?\s*(.*)
```

First group captures showname. *? captures non-greedy, only as few characters as possible, so it does not capture the separator.

Then an optional separator with '.' or '-' and optional whitespace before and after.

Then the "S number E number" section.

Again the optional separator

And a last group with the title.

I made only the interesting positions a capturing group, so you don't get all the separator garbage.

You can add more separator characters to the character group. But these might be captured at the end of showname and the beginning of title.

Test code:

```
string[] d = { "Law & Order Special Victims Unit S05E21 Criminal", "Law & Order Special Victims Unit.S05E21.Criminal", "Law.&.Order.Special.Victims.Unit.S05E21.Criminal", "Law & Order Special Victims Unit - S05E21 - Criminal" };
var r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(.*?)\s*[\.-]?\s*S(\d+)E(\d+)\s*[\.-]?\s*(.*)");
foreach (var v in d)
{
    var match = r.Match(v);
    foreach (var g in match.Groups)
        Console.WriteLine(g);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Edit**

If you need any separator character I'd suggest the following:

```
(.*?)\s*(\W)?\s*S(\d+)E(\d+)\s*(\2)\s*(.*)
```

This assumes, that the separator char is a non-word character, so it hopefully does not clash with the titles. And it assumes a symmetric separator, so left and right separator character must be the same. So it does not capture titles ending in brackets or something like that.

**Edit 2**

Another variation:

```
(.*?)\s*([^A-Za-z0-9])?\s*S(\d+)E(\d+)\s*\2\s*(.*)
```

Since '_' is apparently a word character, I defined the character class myself. The new test case should now work.

Comment: That doesn't work, the problem still exists with the last sample and now it doesn't match the first sample also

Comment: Sorry. Now it is corrected and tested on all 4 cases.

Comment: the . or - can be any character, that's the issue I was facing, it's not hardcoded, it would be an _ or anything else hence the particular issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Should now be fixed. However, there must be any distinguishing fact between the separator and the title characters. Here I suggest non-word characters for the separator, and a symmetric separator character (same left and right). Hope that fixes your problem.

Comment: Pretty close, it doesn't work with `Law & Order Special Victims Unit_S05E21_Criminal`. Also why not just use \W instead of \2?

Comment: Hey, that is all according to taste, and not really part of a general question. '_' was not in the \W group, made it now less restrictive. You can design that as you like. 
And whether you want \2 or the class repeated is also according to your taste. I thought the symmetric separator could be interesting. But you can of course offer another separator char on the right.
Possibly there are even more separator chars possible like ---. Since there is no spec on Movie-File-Names, you have to tweak the Regex according to the needs.